# How to scrape input box value in ruby?

Tags: ruby, web-scraping

I want to scrape rubygems.org, gem install part. But this is not in text it is the value  of the input box, how could I scraps it?

`rubygems.org` the input box which value part I want to scrape

```html
<input type="text" class="gem__code" id="install_text" value="gem install nokogiri" readonly="readonly">
```

My ruby Code

```rb
require "httparty"
require "nokogiri"

req=HTTParty.get("https://rubygems.org/gems/nokogiri")
parse=Nokogiri::HTML(req.body)
val=parse.xpath("//*[@id=\"install_text\"]").text
puts val
```

Please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

You were to close to the final solution I think that the best option to working with ids is using at_css method try this:

```
require "httparty"
require "nokogiri"

req = HTTParty.get("https://rubygems.org/gems/nokogiri")

doc = Nokogiri::HTML req

puts doc.at_css('[id="install_text"]').attributes["value"].value
```

Then execute this script, or in an ruby interpreter:

```
☸ sandas-nonpro (qa) in learn/ruby/stackoverflow via  v3.0.1 
❯ ruby ./nokogiri_rubygems.rb                                                                                              
gem install nokogiri
```

in a pry interactive session:

```
[79] pry(main)> doc.at_css('[id="install_text"]').attributes
=> {"type"=>#(Attr:0xe1c8 { name = "type", value = "text" }),
 "class"=>#(Attr:0xe1dc { name = "class", value = "gem__code" }),
 "id"=>#(Attr:0xe1f0 { name = "id", value = "install_text" }),
 "value"=>#(Attr:0xe204 { name = "value", value = "gem install nokogiri" }),
 "readonly"=>#(Attr:0xe218 { name = "readonly", value = "readonly" })}
[80] pry(main)> doc.at_css('[id="install_text"]').attributes["value"].value
=> "gem install nokogiri"
```